# failed query from catalina log

Tags: tomcat

I have a log file catalina.out in the following location.

```
/opt/apache-tomcat-3/logs/
```

I will like to know if it logs the failed mysql query info.

I will also like to know the kind of errors the people look for in this file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Catalina.out is where log4j and system.out and system.err tend to go, as per the tomcat [wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/Logging). If the application in question has been set up to write out the failed mysql query using one of those methods then it will be in that log.

You can look at adjusting the log4j.properties file to a higher level if that's what used.

I tend to monitor catalina.out for stack traces, too many incorrect logins, and various bits like that.